# Finding maximum value of squared sum

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given k positive integers such that $x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$, find the maximum possible value of $x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_k^2$.

I know we can find its minimum value using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but is there any way to find its maximum value?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is an option. And using Cauchy-Schwarz would give the minimum value I think, not the maximum.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you for pointing it out (the minimum thing). I wrote that mistakenly. And ya I knew that Lagrange multipliers would be good for that, but I don't think it is correct since it gives me x's to be equal to n/k. All the x's need to be positive integer, but it isn't given anywhere that k|n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way without Karamata, though that's an inequality well worth the effort studying.

As the number of possibilities for $x_i$ is finite, there must be at least one possibility which gives a maximal value.  Further, we note that in a maximal solution, there can only be one distinct value other than $1$ that the variables can take.

*Proof*: Suppose $a,b>1$ are present in a maximal solution.  Then we may replace $a, b$ with $a+b-1, 1$, as the sum remains the same and $(a+b-1)^2+1 > a^2+b^2 \iff (a-1)(b-1)> 0$.

It immediately follows that a maximal solution is having all variables $1$, except possibly one variable which takes the value $n-k+1$.

Comment: Great one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As $t\mapsto t^2$ is convex, using [Karamata’s Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality), the maximum is when all except one variable is zero, as $(n,0,0,\dots,0)\succ (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_k)$.

In the new version with only positive integers, similarly we must have $(n-k+1,1,1...,1)\succ (x_1,x_2,..,x_k)$ and hence the maximum must be $(n-k+1)^2+k-1$.